# For Python 3.4: Is there a grid-like container that doesn’t store values for empty cells?

Tags: containers, python-3.4

I started slowly learning Python on my own less than two years ago and have humble experience with programming outside of that (GWBasic). So I thought before I exert much energy trying to reinvent the wheel myself, I should ask if it has already been invented or been deemed not worth inventing, etc.

I have at least four different goals that all require storing objects (not necessarily binary data) in a grid structure with accessible columns, rows and cells. I see that a list can act like a grid by storing other lists of equal length and I like how straight-forward and unsophisticated that solution is. The down side (however significant) is that there must be an object at every index in every list. For me this raises the question, is there a container object out there made to store row/column "islices" or cell values individually that can generate a specified region of the grid when needed by yielding a default value for every empty cell? Or is there anything similar to that?

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store cell values individually.  eg:

```
sparse_grid = {(r1, c1): value1, (r2, c2):value2 }
```

Also, a [defauldict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be used to return default values.  See the [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) with the `constant_factory` for how to supply the default value.

Comment: Thank you for this. A dict with (x,y) keys would seem to do what I was asking about and it even rivals nested lists in terms of simplicity. I wonder which one, nested lists or a dict with (x,y) keys performs faster with a lot of data going in and out.

Comment: You can see the time complexity of lists and dicts here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.  You're better off getting the logic of your program correct before you start worrying about speed though.